# Error 404 for special char in path ImageResizer Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, imageresizer

I'm using [ASP.NET Image Resizing](http://imageresizing.net/) on a MVC website that use images in a azure container.

I've got 3.4.2 version of both Image Resizer and AzureRedear2 plugin.

If I upload a file in a azure container and serve it on my site with url like
http://www.example.com/azure/myfile.jpg?mode=crop&width=111&height=168
everything works fine.

But if I use a url like
http://www.example.com/azure/my+file.jpg?mode=crop&width=111&height=168
I've got a 404 error and no image is displayed.

Is this a bug or something that cannot be fixed?

Comment: Can you try by escaping `+` with `%2B`? So your URL would be: _http://www.example.com/azure/my%2Bfile.jpg?mode=crop&width=111&height=168.

Comment: Have you tried to encode the filename like: HttpUtility.UrlEncode("my+file.jpg")

Comment: Yes, I tried but still 404.

Comment: Can you check the name of the blob in the blob container? Is it saved as `my+file.jpg' or something else?

Comment: It's saved as my+file.jpg cause if I request the file directly, it is served.

Comment: What is the exact URL you use to request the file directly? [Azure requires all special characters (including space) to be URL encoded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd135715.aspx)

Comment: This is the image
https://islostorage.blob.core.windows.net/product/2910/Big/mirto-camoscio-+-vernice-nera.jpg